# How to navigate internally within same Page using links in HTML5, JQuery mobile..?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a scenario, wherein I am trying to navigate within page of my Android App using links. I am using [HTML5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5) with [Phonegap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Cordova) and JQuery Mobile.

For ex, I am having:

```
<h3><a name="try"/> Header2 </h3>
```

and when I give,

```
<a href="#try"> Navigate to Header2 </a>
```

in order to navigate to the Header section within the same page, I am unable to do so. Can someone please provide some solution for this problem..?

As part of solution given by @Adleer, tried working with  for multiple sections of the same HTML document. Below is a sample code for reference:

```
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="page3">
<div data-role="header">
<h3>Common diphthongs</h3></div></div>

<div data-role="page" id="diphthongs">
<div data-role="content">
<ul>
<li> Test </li>
<li> item2 </li>
</ul>
</div></div>

<div data-role="page" id="vowels">
<div data-role="content">
<ul>
<li><a href="#diphthongs"> Link to Diphthongs </a> </li>
<li><a href="#page3"> Link to page3 </a> </li> </li>
</ul>
</div></div>
</body>
```

The above code is for reference to one of the provided solutions.

Comment: you should use div with `data-role=page` to navigate internally.

Comment: @omar, thanks!! Trying to work on that lines...

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/t84S3/ unless you want to scroll to a specific div within the same page, in that case you need to use `.silentScroll()`

Comment: @Omar, can you pls provide this as an answer with a silentscroll example..? I will be checking it, whether it's the answer, by tomorrow..other two solutions, didn't work...

Comment: i did try, not sure, whether i did it correctly..can you pls. provide a link and an example ..?

Comment: Check this http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/yggF5/

Comment: i did try...not sure wats the mistake..looking into it...meanwhile, can yu pls look frm yur side..?http://fiddle.jshell.net/cmani87/JJkEq/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35919/discussion-between-omar-and-mannii88)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the last jsfiddle you added, you had some mistakes in selectors and HTML attributes. You either use `id` attribue with a unique identifier, and selector `$('#Anyname')` - case sensitive (mind capital/small letters) - to access properties of that element.

Or, use `name` attribute with a unqiue identifier, and selector `$('[name=Somename]')` - case sensitive (mind capital/small letters) - to access properties of that element.

To scroll down to any element, jQuery Mobile has its' own scroll function `.silentScroll()`. Note that `$.mobile.silentScroll()` has no animation, unlike `.animate({ scrollTop: value }, animation-speed)`.

> **[Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/XsNpA/)**

```
$('selector').on('click', function () {
  var position = $.mobile.activePage.find('#vowels2').get(0).offsetTop;
  $.mobile.silentScroll(position);
});
```

Where `.get(0).offsetTop` is the *y* axis position value of the target element, and `$.mobile.activePage` is the active/current page/viewport.

Comment: Hi Omar, The code is working fine in JsFiddle, but not in Emulator!! What this could possibly mean..?I am using Phonegap framework, not on native android.

Comment: @Mannii88 It should work fine with phonegap. Have you tested it on a device not an emulator?

Comment: No...I was testing it with emulator only...Will try out with a device and let you know.!

Answer (score 3):

You want to reference an id, you can use a paragraph, a span or a div.

```
<span id="try">Header2</span>
```

You can then navigate to it as expected:

```
<a href="#try">Navigate to Header2</a>
```

Also, the way you were doing

```
<a name="try/> Header2
```

is incorrect, your quote closing is missing and you're not closing the a attribute properly.

Comment: Thanks @Jonast92 for the answer..But, I think you missed the point!! it's jquery mobile...Working in a different way..! :) still discussions are going on abt other answers...yu can have a look and provide your thoughts..!! :)

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I used it in razor page in blazor app. It goes to a new page "/try"

Answer (score 0):

You want to reference an id, you can use a paragraph, a span or a div.

```
<span id="try">Header2</span>
```

You can then navigate to it as expected:

```
<a href=" #try" data-ajax="false">Navigate to Header2</a>
```

When you set `data-ajax` false it works :)
Just tried...