# Scrolling top of the Popup window with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scrollbar, scrolltop

I have popup window and there is a  in it with the id of PopupDiv and I want to scroll top after returning the Ajax request made to the Controller (when there is an error, I return message with Json and I display it on the popup window). I have found many different ways on web and tried the methods below, but none of them is not working (they works a whole page instead of popup window). Any idea?

**View:**

```
<div id="PopupDiv" style="height: 421px; overflow-y: scroll; margin-top: -7px; margin-bottom:-14px ">

<script>
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("Create", "Issue")',
        data: formdata,
        dataType: "json",
        processData: false,
        contentType: false, 
        success: function (response) {
        if (!response.success) {

        //I tried the following by one by one, but none of them is working:
        messageThread.scrollTop = messageThread.scrollHeight;
        $('html, form').animate({ scrollTop: $('#PopupDiv').position().top }, 'slow');          
        $(window).scrollTop(300);
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: "1024px" }, 5000);
        var objDiv = document.getElementById("#PopupDiv");
        objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Is there anyone else having an idea regarding to this problem???

Comment: Please see my answer on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18752030/scroll-a-scrollable-div-to-its-top-programatically/30990423#30990423) page.