# HTML5 navigation on the same page

Tags: html

I have a problem with navigation in html5. I watched a lot of tutorials and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I want to navigate on the same page.

```
<header>
<nav>
  <a href="#top">TOP</a>
  <a href="#middle">MIDDLE</a>
  <a href="#bottom">BOTTOM</a>
</nav>
 </header>
<main>
<article>
  <section><h1><a name=”top”></a>TOP</h1>
    <figure>
<img src="1.jpg">
</figure>
  <p>...</p>
</section>
```

Comment: If https://stackoverflow.com/q/18338996/1531971 doesn't help explain why, exactly. Do this by explaining in the question with an [edit]

Comment: There's no element with a name/id of `middle` or `bottom` in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh dear... You're using wrong quotes!

Replace `<a name=”top”>` with `<a id="top">` and it should work.

- 1st error: using obsolete attribute, `name` instead of `id`.
- 2nd error: using wrong quotes, `”` instead of `"`.

Comment: @MayaKP are you sure? do you see that `”` differs from `"`?

Comment: @MayaKP You are welcome =) I would be happy if you accept & upvote the answer. See help article for details: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

This will allow navigation on same page to go to the top, middle, and bottom.

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <a href="#top">TOP</a>
    <a href="#middle">MIDDLE</a>
    <a href="#bottom">BOTTOM</a>
  </nav>
</header>
<main>
  <article>
    <section><a name="top">TOP</a>
      <figure> <img src="https://placem.at/people?h=700"> </figure>
      <p>...</p>
    </section>
    <section><a name="middle">MIDDLE</a>
      <figure><img src="https://placem.at/people?h=500"></figure>
      <p>...</p>
    </section>
    <section> <a name="bottom">BOTTOM</a>
      <figure><img src="https://placem.at/people?h=400"></figure>
      <p>...</p>
    </section>
  </article>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

prefer `id` over `name` for anchors.

```html
<header>
<nav>
  <a href="#top">TOP</a>
  <a href="#middle">MIDDLE</a>
  <a href="#bottom">BOTTOM</a>
</nav>
 </header>
<main>
<article>
  <section><h2 id="top">TOP</h2>
    <figure>
<img src="https://placem.at/people?h=700">
</figure>
  <p>...</p>
</section>
  <section><h2 id="middle">MIDDLE</h2>
    <figure>
<img src="https://placem.at/people?h=500">
</figure>
  <p>...</p>
</section>
  <section><h2 id="bottom">BOTTOM</h2>
    <figure>
<img src="https://placem.at/people?h=400">
</figure>
  <p>...</p>
</section>
</article>
</main>
```

Comment: Addition: the `name` attribute of `<a>` is obsolete as per HTML5. So yes, naXa is completely right.

Comment: @MayaKP I've just noticed something in your code. please read my second answer.